# How to generate m3u8 link for premium show in tango live APP

Tags: hyperlink, stream, private, live, m3u8

tango me is a live broadcast application like bigo live or periscope, its work also on browser (https://www.tango.me/live/nearby)

It is not difficult to find m3u8 codes with filter while streaming in public stream.

https://cinema-us-west.tango.me/v1/d1647b23436c8fa829973a19218b1a53/master.m3u8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hinpt.jpg)

But when the broadcaster opens a private stream, that stream is encrypted and I cannot access m3u8 codes. (encryption is probably done with aes-128 but I'm not sure)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjfCT.jpg)

Does anyone have any advice on deciphering this private stream ? or anyone know how to generate m3u8 link for premium braodcast?
I don't want to download, it will be enough if I just got the link from the online hls player

Thank you very much for any help